# Expandable Div Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a site (lowrateadvisor.com) I am working on getting an expandable div at the top of the page to work.  I can get it to work in jsfiddle.net/3shEE/95/, just not on the site.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
CSS
#expandable a{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:underline;
}
#expandable a:hover{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
#expandable {
    width: 100%; 
    height:35px;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
font-size:11px;
text-align:center;
}

#expandable.dropped { 
    background: #666; 
    color: white; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111 }

#expandable span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px; text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#expandable ul {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="expandable">
    <span> Get the lowest possible rates on pre approved home loans, mortgages and refinancing your home.</span>

    <ul>
        <li>We will never...<br /></li>
        <li>&raquo; Ask for your SSN.</li>
        <li>&raquo; Ask for a credit card.</li>
        <li>&raquo; Store your information.</li>
        <li>&raquo; Hassle or Pressure any applicant.</li>
        <li> <a href="http://lowrateadvisor.com/apply-now/">Get Pre Approved</a> | <a href="http://lowrateadvisor.com/get-pre-approved/">Get A Quote</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>​
```

JQUERY

```
$("#expandable").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"height":"200px"},1000).addClass("dropped");
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"height":"35px"},1000).removeClass("dropped");
});
​
```

Comment: There is some typo mistake in your code that's why its giving error of "illegal character". Retype the code again not copy paste.

Comment: I really need help dude.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Kundan - Thanks I will give it a try.  I have special chars as far as arrows, would that be an issue?

Comment: @kundan - Thanks but that did not work for me.  I have a slider installed using the same version of jquery could this be the issue?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flowrateadvisor.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see any typo mistake.... just a SyntaxError: illegal character on line 67
Try using jquery 1.8.2 and this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#expandable").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height":"200px"},1000).addClass("dropped");
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height":"35px"},1000).removeClass("dropped");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have a missing }); at the end of the script (on the webpage).

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I got it to work.  I had to remove the slider to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when copying code from JSFiddle.

The last semicolon (sometimes last but one) of your jQuery code is copied as an illegal character. Try to delete the last line `});` and retype it by hand.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it to work. I had to remove the slider to get it to work.